# Proc SQL and removing duplicates by a single variable

Tags: sql, duplicates, concatenation, sas

PROC SQL newbie here - I want to use Proc SQL to concatenate (stack) ID and Race data from two different datasets, while also removing duplicates by ID only (and NOT by both ID and Race) - is this possible? For example, after combining the data below, I only want the first instance of ID=1 (where Race=white), and not both {(1, White) and (1, Black)}

Sample Data:

```
DATA SAMPLE1;
    INPUT ID RACE$;
    DATALINES;
    1 WHITE
    2 BLACK
    3 WHITE
    4 BLANK
    ;
RUN; 
DATA SAMPLE2;
    INPUT ID RACE$;
    DATALINES;
    5 HISPANIC
    6 ASIAN
    7 HISPANIC
    8 ASIAN
    1 BLACK
    ;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't something that SQL is quite as good at as normal SAS, but it's certainly possible.

A few options:

Outer join, with COALESCE.  Harder to write than other options as you have to write each variable out twice in the initial select.

```
proc sql;
select coalesce(s1.id,s2.id) as id, coalescec(s1.race,s2.race) as race from (
(select * from sample2) s2
full outer join
(select *,"1" as sample1 from sample1) s1
on s2.id=s1.id);
quit;
```

Union with an EXISTS subquery.  Slower depending on the size of the tables; if this is a 10k table combined with a 10 row table, this is a fast solution; if it's 2 10k tables, this is slow.

```
proc sql;
select * from sample1
union
select * from sample2 where not exists (
  select 1 from sample1 where sample1.id=sample2.id
);
quit;
```

Union with a JOIN.  Might be faster than the above query, depending on indexing and such.

```
proc sql;
select * from sample1
union
select sample2.* from sample2 
  left join sample1
  on sample1.id=sample2.id
  where missing(sample1.id);
quit;
```

But the easiest solution in SAS is undoubtedly to do it in SAS.

```
data sample12_view/view=sample12_view;
set sample1 sample2;
run;

proc sort nodupkey data=sample12_view out=sample12;
by id;
run;
```

or

```
data sample12;
merge sample1(in=s1) sample2(in=s2);
by id;
run;
```

In that case s2 replaces s1, so if you prefer the other option change the order on the merge statement.

Comment: The best way is it do it with proc sort and option nodupkeys. Add dupout=dups to get all duplicats in a sas dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you ought to specify what duplicates to keep - SQL tries to be deterministic. Something like this should work:

```
proc sql;
    create table both_samples as
        select * from (
            (select *
            from sample1 )
            union ( select *
                    from sample2 )
        )
        group by id
        having race = max( race )
    ;
quit;
proc print data = both_samples noobs;
run;

1    WHITE
2    BLACK
3    WHITE
4    BLANK
5    HISPANIC
6    ASIAN
7    HISPANIC
8    ASIAN
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the answer that you specified:

```
proc sql;
create table all as 
    select monotonic() as _n_, * from sample1
union all
    select monotonic() as _n_, * from sample2; 

create table distinct_ids as 
    select id, min(_n_) as _n_ from all group by 1;

create table results as
    select a.id
        ,(select race from all where all.id=a.id and all._n_=a._n_) as race
    from distinct_ids a;
```